# Why is j always = 4 at the beginning of this insertion sort?

Tags: python, sorting, insertion

I'm tracing over insertion, bubble, and selection sort to gain a better understanding/practice tracing.

I'm using Python Tutor to help, and no matter the size of the list, at the beginning of this insertion sort j is always [4]? At the line j = a[i].

What IS a[i]? Why are we setting it equal to j? I mean obviously it's [4] lol but I can't figure out where it's getting that 4 from. Also it doesn't seem to be the index 4 as Python Tutor is indicating, because if that were true it'd be equal to '5'. When I add a line 'print(j)' under j = a[i], the first number j comes up as is the number 4, which is index [1].

Am I just burnt out and being totally stupid rn/missing something obvious? Lol

Thanks!!!

```
def insertion(a):

    for i in range(1,len(a)):
       j = a[i]

           while i>0 and a[i-1]>j:
              print(a[i-j])
              a[i] = a[i-1]
              i = i-1
              a[i] = j

    return (a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [2,4,3,1,5,6]
    print(insertion(lst))
```

Comment: As a hint, you might want to `print(i, j)`. What do you see? You already understand lists start at index `0`, all that remains now is to piece it together.

Comment: Ohhhhh my goodness I see! Ahaha whoops, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

- We are assigning a[i] to j because we are trying to find a position between
  0..i-1 to fit a[i].
- We assume a[0..i-1] is already sorted. So it would be enough if we go backward until a[i - 1] > j.
- While you are starting your loop, your index, i would be equal to 1. So j, will
  print 4.